# Decrypt certificate validate signature hash

Tags: powershell, encryption, hash

Object: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service?ref_=pe_679090_102923190#checking-the-signature-of-the-request

- Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.
- Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to produce the derived hash value (not sure if this means the entire POST or just the "request" JSON)

Sample SIGNATURE:

```
FosqGd+Djx2PAXuER7msZwOsGok+BWZUXMj6LjEIDkhGp0yvmB/oB76C9Mu5fhL6ZH0AgZ862sZYArp2VZnANGy2fAzTyUa1dWL+uZuO4l9jAxq/7Y30W9+V1rStWF8LcYK48iaHdfsqPFm9otOWSLoIYhg9bo62rrCDBo9TeQOt8S63lrBTWc6csEQ0PRVsplkfnAb3edv46g0c7Mg4B3h+uQfq3+RveoKVrUDAEfg1SN7HLWtjxPcLJ1pxOYa29zu56aqiF/96G79gNyQMrUZ7wdnElWWA+lYgHNWAxCibKdzs7QiU1hgbLR+g45+33nHn+M2qgKjjGFcDtaMmPA==
```

Signature cert chain URL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/echo.api/echo-api-cert-4.pem

Sample Post JSON:

```json
{"session":{"sessionId":"SessionId.d6d80552-79bf-445a-9e88-5f845a368718","application":{"applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.29dff22d-929c-4c74-bbe2-e2a9c83316c5"},"attributes":{},"user":{"userId":"amzn1.ask.account."},"new":true},"request":{"type":"IntentRequest","requestId":"EdwRequestId.c4a78877-5328-4009-9c1c-f6b8783186a2","locale":"en-US","timestamp":"2017-01-29T03:35:40Z","intent":{"name":"GetMovie","slots":{"Keyword":{"name":"Keyword"},"Genre":{"name":"Genre"}}}},"version":"1.0"}
```

I'm at a complete loss how to use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.
`.GetPublicKey()` returns fairly long `System.Byte`, but now what?

Current code:

```bsh
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $dlPath
# 5.- Base64-decode the Signature header value on the request to obtain the encrypted signature
$encryptedSignatureBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Json.signature)

# 6.- Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value       
$publicKey = $cert.GetPublicKey() #returns long System.Byte
$assertedHash = $cert.PublicKey.Key.Decrypt($encryptedSignatureBytes, $false) #Exception calling "Decrypt" with "2" argument(s): "Key does not exist.
$assertedHash = $cert.PublicKey.Key.DecryptValue($encryptedSignatureBytes) #Exception calling "DecryptValue" with "1" argument(s): "Method is not supported."

# 7.- Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to produce the derived hash value    
$requestBodySHA1 = $(Get-StringHash $Json.requestBody)

# 8.- Compare the asserted hash value and derived hash values to ensure that they match    
if ($assertedHash -eq $requestBodySHA1)
{
    #todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being easier than expected once I understood the actual requirement. In order to compare the signature and Amazon post request, all I had to do was get the request as Byte[] the Signature was already Byte[] from Base64 conversion, then feed it in to the function $cert.PublicKey.Key.VerifyData
If I change any byte in either the Signature or Request it fails.

```
# 7.- Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to produce the derived hash value
$requestBodyBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($req)
# 8.- Compare the asserted hash value and derived hash values to ensure that they match
$sha1Oid = [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig]::MapNameToOID('SHA1')
if(!($cert.PublicKey.Key.VerifyData($requestBodyBytes, $sha1Oid, $encryptedSignatureBytes)))
{
    $validErr += "`nFailed request hash comparison to signature."
}
```